# How to make JOIN in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, testing, join

My application with JPA (Hibernate) and Spring. My enitites are:

**Department**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16 )
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16 )
    private UUID uuid;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "login", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_fk", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

}
```

**DAO** for Department:

```
@Repository("departmentDao")
public class DepartmentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public UUID save(Department entity) {
        log.info("Department entity will be persisted", entity);
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity.getUuid();
    }

    public List<Department> getAllWithUsers() {
        log.info("Select all departments");
        CriteriaQuery<Department> criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Department.class);
        criteria.from(Department.class).fetch("users");
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Whan I run the code in Main class it joins the entities (**but duplicates them, why?**):

**Main**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring.xml");
UserDao userDao = (UserDao) context.getBean("userDao");
DepartmentDao departmentDao = (DepartmentDao) context.getBean("departmentDao");

Department newDep = new Department("WebDepartment", new Date());
departmentDao.save(newDep);

User newUser1 = new User("Test1", newDep);
User newUser2 = new User("Test2", newDep);
userDao.save(newUser1);
userDao.save(newUser2);

List<Department> deps = departmentDao.getAllWithUsers();

//deps
//[Department{name='WebDepartment', users = ['Test1', 'Test2']}, 
// Department{name='WebDepartment', users = ['Test1', 'Test2']}]
```

Whan I run  a unit test with the same code, list of departments still contains two entities, each of department has empty list of users:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/spring-test.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDao departmentDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void daoTests() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Department newDep = new Department("WebDepartment", new Date());
        departmentDao.save(newDep);

        User newUser1 = new User("Test1", newDep);
        User newUser2 = new User("Test2", newDep);
        userDao.save(newUser1);
        userDao.save(newUser2);
        List<Department> deps = departmentDao.getAllWithUsers();

        //deps
        //[Department{name='WebDepartment', users = []}, 
        // Department{name='WebDepartment', users = []}]
    }
}
```

So, I have two questions. 
1. Why I get two Department-entites?
2. Why **join** works in Main, but in test it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why I get two Department-entites?

It's because you are performing a `JOIN FETCH` query in your DAO:

```
criteria.from(Department.class).fetch("users")
```

This joins the departments with the users resulting in one department-row per user. Since you have two users with that department, the result will contain 2 rows with the same department. What you want here is a `where` clausle instead of a `fetch join`.

> 2. Why join works in Main, but in test it doesn't?

It does work, but you use `FetchType.LAZY` on the user collection within your department. This means the users will only be loaded from the database if you access them. You can use `FetchType.EAGER` to load the users instantly.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misled you. I don't need `where` clause. I need to get **one** department-entity with **two** user-entities inside. As I know, even with `LAZY` fetching I can fetch releated entities from db. Am  I right?

Comment: Ah. I thougth `getAllWithUsers` means get all departments, that have users. So to get all departments with their users you have to just omit the `.fetch("users");` part from your DAO method.

Comment: Yes wiht `LAZY` fetching you can fetch related entities from the db. But you need to actively access that collection to actually laod it. Just using `System.out.println` or anything on the department will not load the users collection if it's lazy fetched.